# AFNetworking 1.x to 3.x migration for NSURLSessionTask?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, nsurlsession, afnetworking-3

I have a old project which is not working in iOS 9. I've read official documentation on AFNetworking and completed most of the migration.

NetworkManager:

```
_requestManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL ]];
//here we can set the request header as the access token once we have logged in.
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[_requestManager setRequestSerializer:requestSerializer];
[_requestManager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
```

Earlier Version:

```
// 2. Create an `NSMutableURLRequest`.
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance].requestManager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:fullPath
                                                                                          parameters:nil
                                                                           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", theAudioItem.media_item_name];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:theAudioItem.media_item_name fileName:fileName mimeType:@"audio/caf"];
}];

// 3. Create and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the `NSMutableURLRequest` that we just created.
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [[NetworkManager sharedInstance].requestManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                            success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    result(YES, @"");
} failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (operation.responseData) {
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

        result(NO, [responseDict valueForKey:@"Message"]);
        [self deleteTmpFilesFromParts:formParts];
    } else {
        result(NO, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to upload media to %@!", gallery.gallery_name]);
        [self deleteTmpFilesFromParts:formParts];
    }


    result(NO, errorMessage);
}];

// 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
[operation setUploadProgressBlock: ^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                     long long totalBytesWritten,
                                     long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    DLog(@"progress is %i %lld %lld", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    progress((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

// 5. Begin!
[operation start];
```

Converted Response: ( updated with comments what gives errors )

```
//No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPRequestSerializer<AFURLRequestSerialization>' declares the selector 'multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:'
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [[NetworkManager sharedInstance].requestManager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:fullPath parameters:nil
                                                                               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", theAudioItem.media_item_name];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:theAudioItem.media_item_name fileName:fileName mimeType:@"audio/caf"];
    }];

    // 3. Create and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the `NSMutableURLRequest` that we just created.
   //No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPSessionManager' declares the selector 'HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:'
    NSURLSessionTask *operation =
        [[NetworkManager sharedInstance].requestManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                success: ^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject) {
        result(YES, @"");
    } failure: ^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

        //Error for operation doesn't have responseData
        if (operation.responseData) {
            NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

            result(NO, [responseDict valueForKey:@"Message"]);
            [self deleteTmpFilesFromParts:formParts];
        } else {
            result(NO, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to upload media to %@!", gallery.gallery_name]);
            [self deleteTmpFilesFromParts:formParts];
        }

        // get the response
        result(NO, errorMessage);
    }];

    // 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
    //No visible @interface for 'NSURLSessionTask' declares the selector 'setUploadProgressBlock:'
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock: ^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                         long long totalBytesWritten,
                                         long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        DLog(@"progress is %i %lld %lld", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        progress((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    // 5. Begin!
    //No visible @interface for 'NSURLSessionTask' declares the selector 'start'
    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent code for `AFHTTPSessionManager` is simply:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[[NetworkManager sharedInstance] requestManager] POST:fullPath parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", theAudioItem.media_item_name];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:theAudioItem.media_item_name fileName:fileName mimeType:@"audio/caf"];
} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    NSLog(@"%.3f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    // success
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    // failure

    // if you need to process the `NSData` associated with this error (if any), you'd do:

    NSData *data = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
    if (data) { ... }
}];
```

This features two major changes from your v1.x code: First, with 2.x they introduced `GET`/`POST`/etc. methods that saved you from manually starting the operation (or adding it to your own queue). Second, with 3.x, they retired `NSOperation` framework of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, and now use `AFHTTPSessionManager` class, where `GET`/`POST`/etc. don't return an `NSOperation` subclass, but rather a `NSURLSessionTask` reference.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, but how can I read failure response data in NSURLSessionDataTask?

Comment: If it fails, the code in the `failure` block will get called.

Comment: I mean there is no property as task.responseData in NSURLSessionDataTask. Cann't I convert it into dictionary and read data using specific key send by webservice? ( sample is in my code snippet )

Comment: The `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey` key has the `NSData` associated with response (if any) in the `failure` block. If you need the `NSHTTPURLResponse` for any reason, that's under `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey`. See revised answer.